# PHP MySQLi query not returning value

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli

I've tried to get this to work in several ways, but I can't get this query to return the Cost value from the database to the $cost variable:

```
$query2 =  "SELECT Cost FROM 'item' WHERE Item = '$item'";
$cost=  $db->query($query2);
```

It seems to be empty when I try to echo it.

(The $item variable is selected from a dropdown list generated from the item-table in the mySQL-db. This works fine and if I echo the value from $item, it returns the name of the item as expected.)

Anybody sees what I'm doing wrong?

I could post my complete code if necessary, but I believe this explanation may be sufficient.

Comment: Wrap off quotes from column and table name instead use backtick

Comment: You need to fetch the result as you will get back a mysql array from the execution

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: `$query2 =  "SELECT Cost FROM item WHERE item = '".$item."'";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declared 'fetch_array'  and Make reference this URL : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

**For Example:-**

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Comment: Marking this as solution as this is what I ended up using and working. (I am sure some of the other suggestions would work too, though.) Thanks to everyone helping!

Answer (score 0):

Change `$query2 =  "SELECT Cost FROM 'item' WHERE Item = '$item'";` to

`$query2 = "SELECT Cost FROM item WHERE item = '".$item."'";`
Assuming `Cost` is your column name, the first `item` is your table name, the second `item` is another column name (Please change your naming convention and not use the same name for table and column). To make your question clearer, please provide us with your table name, your column names so that we can give you a more accurate answer.

Also you will need to escape your `$item` variable by using `'".$item."'` so that you can query from your database proper using that variable.

You will then need to fetch the results from querying the database.
`$results = $db->fetch_all($cost);`
To test that the data were successfully fetched, you can test it by printing it using `print_r($results);` This should return you an array of the results.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you.

```
$input = "100";

$query = "select sal from sal where sal='$input'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
//This will print sal
echo $row['sal'];
```

Please let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: You should change it to at least mysqli if not pdo. And use prepared statements whenever you can,  mysql is deprecated and will throw warnings upon execution.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Cost FROM item WHERE Item = '$item'");
while($x=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$cost=$x['Cost'];
echo $cost;    //here we can return the result 
}
```